# Pass Value in Variable through Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass variable in select query but getting below error.

```
Declare @ChangeComment as varchar(1000)
set @ChangeComment=''
select FirstName,LastName,SalesAmount,@ChangeComment='Test'   
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[DimCustomer] a
left outer join [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] b on a.CustomerKey=b.CustomerKey
```

[image]

Comment: error statement is clear. You cant select and assign something at a time is not possible.

Comment: I need to concatenate value in variable in a loop.Any work around for this.?

Comment: @at9063 Example data and expected results would help.

Comment: In above query i want to capture changes in sales table and customer tables using variable change comments

Comment: Code in comments really doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Please **edit the original question** to include this info. Code in the comments is hard to read and hidden for most of us by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Declare @ChangeComment as varchar(1000)
set @ChangeComment='Test'

    select FirstName,LastName,SalesAmount,@ChangeComment as ChangeComment  
    FROM [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[DimCustomer] a
    left outer join [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] b on a.CustomerKey=b.CustomerKey
```

You don't need to set @ChangeComment in the query because you decide of its value independently from the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dynamic SQL :

```
DECLARE @ChangeComment as varchar(1000)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @ChangeComment='Test'

SET @sql = N'select FirstName,LastName,SalesAmount, '+@ChangeComment+'
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[DimCustomer] a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [AdventureWorksDW2014].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] b on a.CustomerKey=b.CustomerKey'

PRINT @sql -- By using this you will see how SQL Statement looks at the run time before execution. 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with dynamic sql.